# "Database is Locked" error while deploying django webapp on azure

Tags: python, django, azure

I am trying to deploy a django webapp on azure. It appears on the web totally functional, except for one thing, it doesn't let me create a superuser on webssh. Every time I try to run `python manage.py createsuperuser` and after giving all credentials it throws an error

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: database is locked`

I am using default database of django. What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLite is meant to be a lightweight database, and thus can't support a high level of concurrency. OperationalError: database is locked errors indicate that your application is experiencing more concurrency than sqlite can handle in default configuration. This error means that one thread or process has an exclusive lock on the database connection and another thread timed out waiting for the lock the be released.

Python's SQLite wrapper has a default timeout value that determines how long the second thread is allowed to wait on the lock before it times out and raises the OperationalError: database is locked error.

If you're getting this error, you can solve it by:

    Switching to another database backend. At a certain point SQLite becomes too "lite" for real-world applications, and these sorts of concurrency errors indicate you've reached that point.
    Rewriting your code to reduce concurrency and ensure that database transactions are short-lived.
    Increase the default timeout value by setting the timeout database option
```